# TypeError: Actor: Failed to convert parameter 'socket_name' when calling function 'Actor.K2_AttachToActor' on 'BP_Camera_C'

Tags: python-3.x, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am trying to attach an actor on another actor and getting an error. I have two actors spawned in the world and trying to attach to another one.

Here I getting the main actor(actor A) from the world

```
level_actors = unreal.EditorLevelLibrary.get_all_level_actors()
filtered_list = unreal.EditorFilterLibrary.by_actor_tag(level_actors, Car_tag, filter_type=unreal.EditorScriptingFilterType.INCLUDE)
actor = filtered_list[0]
```

Now setting the location and rotation and spawn another actor (actor B) in the world.

```
pos = unreal.Vector(0,0,0)
rot = unreal.Rotator(0,0,0)
ac = unreal.EditorAssetLibrary.load_blueprint_class('/Game/Resim/Blueprints/BP_Camera.BP_Camera')
ac_pos = unreal.EditorLevelLibrary.spawn_actor_from_object(ac, cam_location)
```

Now trying to attach actor B to actor A using the attach_to_actor command:

```
ac_pos.attach_to_actor(actor, None, pos, rot, None, None)
```

and now I am getting the following error

> LogPython: Error: ac_pos.attach_to_actor(actor, None, pos, rot, None,
> None) LogPython: Error: TypeError: Actor: Failed to convert parameter
> ‘socket_name’ when calling function ‘Actor.K2_AttachToActor’ on
> ‘BP_Camera_C_5’ LogPython: Error: TypeError: NativizeProperty: Cannot
> nativize ‘NoneType’ as ‘SocketName’ (NameProperty) LogPython: Error:
> TypeError: Nativize: Cannot nativize ‘NoneType’ as ‘Name’

what may be the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to one of the arguments being `None` instead of an `unreal.Name`.

It looks like the parameters don't quite match up with what's in the function signature. Here's the documentation for that function: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/PythonAPI/class/Actor.html#unreal.Actor.attach_to_actor

You can change the second parameter to `unreal.Name('None')` and do the same with the `unreal.AttachmentRule` values and then you should be set.